# systemd: set openvpn-client@ service TimeoutStopUSec?

Tags: systemd, openvpn

I set up an openvpn client on ubuntu 18.04, creating `/etc/openvpn/client/foo.conf`.

Whenever I stop the service,

```
sudo systemctl stop openvpn-client@foo.service
```

it hangs for 90 seconds, and the logs show the graceful termination timing out:

```
Stopping OpenVPN tunnel for foo...
openvpn-client@foo.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
openvpn-client@foo.service: Killing process 12737 (openvpn) with signal SIGKILL.
openvpn-client@foo.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
openvpn-client@foo.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Stopped OpenVPN tunnel for foo.
```

I'm still trying to figure out the underlying problem, but in the meantime I'd like to reduce the `TimeoutStopUSec` setting for this one service.

```
systemctl show openvpn-client@foo.service -p TimeoutStopUSec
TimeoutStopUSec=1min 30s
```

If this were a unit I'd created a unit file for, I'd know what to do, but how can I do this for the service that ubuntu generates automatically?

Comment: You can create an override file in `/etc/systemd/system/openvpn-client@foo.service.d/override.conf` with your timeout paramater

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution.

```
sudo systemctl edit openvpn-client@foo.service
```

Add the following:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStopSec=30s
```

Reload configs and restart service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart openvpn-client@foo.service
```